# Musicians Unions In The Modern Day

Tags: performing, history

Historically, the [AFM](http://afm.org) was the place to be to get anything done with music performance; or so that's what I heard growing up.  But I don't hear much about it now.  This was even the case while I was working on my undergraduate degree in music performance surrounded by professional performers.

I understand it provided some benefits, and protection like all unions, but in this privatized day and age, is it still worthwhile to have an affiliation with a musician's union?  Do they offer benefits you simply can not receive without affiliation?

Are people being refused service because of being in one?  Not being in one?

**I purely want to see what benefits (or lack thereof) they offer to performing musicians.**

Comment: How can this be opinion based when I've only stated I'm looking at facts and literal benefits of being/not being in the union?  As a union, their white sheets are quite evident and plenty of perks can be addressed in certain.

Comment: Real-world cases with real musicians can assert these perks or refute them without opinion.

Comment: I did not down vote but I was tempted. One could ask a question about political topic for example, and then say "I'm not looking for opinions" but your responses would be opinions without a very careful wording of the question. Perhaps you can break your question into parts that are more quantifiable.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it seems really broad to me. Should a rock band guitarist join a union? A famous soloist? A back-row violinist? The benefits to one will be worthless to another.

Comment: I would guess any benefits would simply be member benefits they offer.  I know that many clubs and bars don't want to hire musicians that are members of PRO's because they don't want to pay the PRO's.  So in some cases being a member of certain organizations who purport to protect your rights (so they can make a profit) may actually close doors for you as a performing musician.  Join the union and get the t-shirt -  but don't tell anyone you are a member.  That's just my opinion.

Comment: Over here, any public venue that hosts bands **has** to pay the PRS/PPL so you will get royalties. PRS are **very** good at taking venues to court if they don't pay :-)

Comment: What do you mean by “this privatized age?” If that has a meaning, please explain it with examples. If it is meaningless, please edit it out. “The modern day” is also essentially meaningless without explanation and examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My essential list of organisations to belong to as a musician in the UK includes the PRS and PPL in order to be paid royalties (like ASCAP, BMI, and SESAC in the US) and the Musician's Union for the following:

- Instrument insurance as Tim mentioned
- £1million public liability insurance (quite important to a band with pyro...)
- legal and contract advice
- free hearing tests
- free music industry seminars
- free general guidance

And various other benefits including networking opportunities. I would assume the equivalent unions in other countries would offer similar.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about other countries, but in U.K. there's the Musicians' Union. As a member, I was entitled to £2,000 of instrument insurance, topped up if necessary, which was a nice thing to have. The M.U. habitually chased up promoters who still owed money for performances, and warned against bad promoters. On occasions, I could get a pro-forma for contracts for gigs. Some gigs needed all band players to be members, work for t.v., etc. A minimum fee was stipulated - but for 'ordinary' gigs, often undercut. Membership was free for those in full time education. An amount, £1000 I think, was available towards funeral costs for paid up members. Something to die for!

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, orchestra musicians belong to the American Federation of Musicians as a matter of course.  The AFM is location-based and oriented towards professionals such as studio, show and classical musicians.  Other musicians can join [AFM Local 1000](https://local1000.org/).  Check out the website for the benefits.